# LLDB show pointer as an array in the GUI mode

Tags: arrays, user-interface, lldb

I start using LLDB for debugging my C code recently and figured out almost everything. Previously I was using Clion's debug functionality that relies on LLDB as well(it is running on MacOS). LLDB's pseudo-GUI mode is very comfortable to use, but I didn't figure out how to make LLDB show pointer as array in the GUI mode. I know that I can get array elements' values using "parray 10 ptr" in command line mode, but switching between GUI and command-line mode is not comfortable. In Clion I can achieve this doing something like "*f_stack @ 15" or if it is a two dimensional array I can watch each line using "*(cache[2]) @ 15". Is there any way of achieving similar functionality in LLDB GUI(or pseudo GUI) mode?

I tried commands like display and "type format" but they were not helpful.